# angular2 quickly navigating to routes stalls the subscriber

Tags: angular

In component 1, inside my ngOnit, I'm subscribing to a service method which calls a DB for some stuff. Loads my page just fine within 1.5 second. I then navigate forward to page/component 2, which has a back button, which navigates me back to view 1.

```
backBtn(){    
        this.router.navigate(['conversationlist'])
    }
```

View 1, then loads the ngOnit subscriber again, or at least should. It happens for the most part if i slowly navigate between the views. However, if i quickly enter view 1, then backBtn(), the component 1 subscriber method stalls, and takes about 20 secs to load. This is the method I'm calling inside view 1 ngOnit. Again, if i quickly navigate between the pages, this function takes a very long time. However, if i navigate to page 2 from page one, wait a few seconds then navigate back its usually fine.

Thoughts on why this is stalling out/or lagging so hard when quickly navigating?

```
ngOnInit() {


        this.getConvAndMessageSub = this._conversationListService.getConversationListAndMessages(0, listBatch).subscribe(
            data => {
                if(data){

                        for(let convo of data.conversationList)
                        {
                            this.conversationList.push(convo)

                        }
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }

    ngOnDestroy(){
        this.getConvAndMessageSub.unsubscribe();
    }
```

And here is the services code:

```
getConversationListAndMessages(offset, batch){
        this.clearConversationList();

        const token = localStorage.getItem('token') ? '?token=' + localStorage.getItem('token') : '';
        return this._http.get('getConversationList/' + offset + '/' + batch + token )
            .map(response => {
                const convoList =         response.json().data.conversationList;

                this.myUser = response.json().data.myUser;
                let count = 0;

                if(response.json().data.conversationList.length == 0){
                    return {conversationList:'', myUser:this.myUser}
                }
                for(let convo of convoList){
                        this.setupUserObjects(convo);
                        this.getMessages(convo._id, -1, 0).subscribe(
                        data => {

                            convo.messages = data['messages'];

                            for(let message of data['messages']){
                                if(message.subscribersSeen.indexOf(myUser.uid) == -1){
                                    convo.unreadCount++;
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        error => {
                            console.log(error)
                        }
                    );

                    this.conversationList.push(convo)
                    count++;
                    if(count == convoList.length){

                        return {conversationList:this.conversationList, myUser:this.myUser}
                    }
                }


            })
            .catch(error => Observable.throw(error.json()));

    }
```

Comment: Sounds interesting. Have you tried removing the subscription on ngDestroy?

Comment: Could also be useful to see a bit more of "component 1"

Comment: Yes i updated code with more Component 1 info, and yes i removed subscription on destroy

Comment: @Fiddles ^see above code

Comment: @Fiddles here is also something else i noticed...i can go between the first and second view, but on the 4th time going back and fourth it stalls. Always the fourth time. it doesn't happen locally, only on a deployed app through EBS...

Answer (score 0):

After alot of debugging, I noticed that i had some nested Subscriber methods. I was unsubscribing from some, but not all. After i made sure i was unsubscribing on component change. this fixed the issue.